# Scan characters depending on a pattern

Tags: c++, scanf

I found this code in a competitive programming book for ICPC. The objective is to scan inputs which have a pattern where there are N numbers like 0.4586... (starting with 0. and terminating with ...). I tried giving the inputs but on pressing enter key the entire while loop executes at once and I don't get the chance to input the numbers. So I tried using spaces but that doesn't work either. Nothing gets scanned in the while loop however the code works fine if I remove the while loop.
Can someone explain this behaviour.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

char digits[100];                                       

int main() {
    int N;
    scanf("%d", &N);
    
    while (N--) {                                       
        scanf("0.%[0-9]...", &digits);                  
        printf("the digits are 0.%s\n", digits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Code gets stuck as it never read the `'\n'`.  Try `" 0.%99[0-9]..."`: add space and width.

Comment: Unrelated: [Why should I **not** `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.).

Comment: In the scanf `&digits` should be `digits`. There's no need for the `&`.